# HTML CSS: change color of label, when option is selected

Tags: html, css

I want to style a label of a select-tag in html. When the user didn't pick any 
option, the color of the label should be white. If the user picked an option, the label should switch to white.

html code:

```
    <label class="titel" for="titel">Titel:</label>
      <select class="titel" name="titel">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Proffessor">Prof.</option>
        <option value="Doctor">Dr.</option>
      </select>
```

css code:

```
label.titel{color: white;}
```

What i tried, but didn't worked:

```
select.titel:checked + label.titel{color: black;}
```

I searched and i found out, for this kind of tasks the :checked pseudoclass is helpful. I can change the label color of radio buttons or checkboxes, when checked but not the label of a select-tag when option is checked.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**Edit:** To make it more clear, as it mentioned @Rembrand Reyes in a comment "The drop down when blank will have Title displayed white, but when the user picks title, it will color the label black?"

Comment: So if I understand correctly. The drop down when blank will have Title displayed white, but when the user picks title, it will color the label black?

Comment: @RembrandtReyes exactly! Sorry if this wasn't clear

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: Simply put there is no supported method for this, the `+` you are using will select the next sibling not the previous. In order to achieve what you want you should alter your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above in the comment by @Peter M, you can't select the previous sibling using "+". What you can do is make use of Javascript to add the CSS style for the label onchange of select option like shown below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
        var eSelect = document.getElementById('title');
        var optOther = document.getElementById('title-label');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            optOther.style.color = 'black';
        }
}
```

```css
.titel
{
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <label class="titel" id="title-label" for="titel">Titel:</label>
      <select class="titel" id="title" name="titel" selected="">>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Proffessor">Prof.</option>
        <option value="Doctor">Dr.</option>
      </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The :checked pseudo selector only works with input radio and checkbox elements. It may work in some browsers when applied to the option element rather than the select, but as far as I'm aware there's no way to achieve what you're looking for across all browsers.

Might be possible with javascript though.